# How can YouTube and Twitch override the autoplay policy for videos with audio?

Tags: html, attributes, autoplay

I know that Google Chrome has an autoplay policy where videos with audio cannot be autoplayed. How come websites like YouTube and Twich are able to bypass this? How can they autoplay videos with audio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like they're specially white-listed.

> Chrome does this by learning your preferences. If you don’t have
> browsing history, Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we
> see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound. As
> you browse the web, that list changes as Chrome learns and enables
> autoplay on sites where you play media with sound during most of your
> visits, and disables it on sites where you don’t. This way, Chrome
> gives you a personalized, predictable browsing experience.

source:
https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/

Comment: Just for the record, I'm not a fan of this approach. It makes competing against larger companies that much harder. Nor do I think Google should be the gatekeeper here (especially when they run sites like YouTube).

Comment: @Ami Is there a place I can see those 1000 sites they whitelisted? Also is there a way around that in 2022?

Comment: For those non-listed here are rules: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/