# How to bypass HTML5 Video Autoplay

Tags: html5-video, autoplay

How are sites like YouTube able to autoplay videos without muting audio but it's not possible to achieve the same using the `<video>` element embedded on a page?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409015/how-can-youtube-and-twitch-override-the-autoplay-policy-for-videos-with-audio#62614169) might help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can YouTube and Twitch override the autoplay policy for videos with audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409015/how-can-youtube-and-twitch-override-the-autoplay-policy-for-videos-with-audio)