# Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites

Tags: google-chrome, video, autoplay

When I looked for How can YouTube and Twitch override the autoplay policy for videos with audio, I found this [Stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409015/how-can-youtube-and-twitch-override-the-autoplay-policy-for-videos-with-audio).

> Chrome does this by learning your preferences. If you don’t have
> browsing history, Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we
> see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound. As
> you browse the web, that list changes as Chrome learns and enables
> autoplay on sites where you play media with sound during most of your
> visits, and disables it on sites where you don’t. This way, Chrome
> gives you a personalized, predictable browsing experience.

source: https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/

Is there a place where I can see those domains that Google white-listed for new users?

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a place where I can see those domains that Google white-listed for new users?"*

Maybe this Chrome link is what you're looking for: `chrome://media-engagement/`

For me it says `Min Sessions` (for autoplay with sound) must be **20**. 
Then further down is a list of `Sessions with playback` so any site having **20** or more session and a score above **0.5** can **autoplay with sound**.