# How can I autoplay a video (as Youtube does!)?

Tags: video, youtube, html5-video

I know the Chrome policy about autoplaying videos: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

But Youtube auto plays a video when you enter a page, without interacting or clicking anything.

You load a Youtube video page, you see the ads (that actually are videos too), and after that you see the main video.

No clicking at all, no interaction even with mouse or keyboard.

Is Youtube overriding Chrome policy ?

How?!?!?!

Comment: I don't think the Google owned Youtube is overriding the Google owned Chrome's autoplay policy. Youtube is just trusted not to be irresponsible, and it autoplays because if the visitor goes to such a site they expect video. I don't know about your device but on mine even a [Bitchute example video](https://www.bitchute.com/video/YDwdOrHxBc3t/) plays without me clicking anything...  Also if you visit any site regularly, [after some visits Chrome will start doing autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71688356/2057709).